# I can not post Yammer via Rest API using Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, yammer

Hi I would like to Create JavaScript app which post message to Yammer, using Yammer REST API.
but I have a limitation. I Can Not use Yammer SDK to post message. so, I written code of ajax.

However, In this code Doesn't work.
XMLHTTPrequest  is always "access denied".

why this code doesn't work?

MY Yammer network allow 3rd party app.

```js
function sendData() {

    var messagebody = new Object();
    messagebody.body = "This is test";
    messagebody.group_id ="4627253"
    
    //get accToken 
    accToken = responseObject.access_token.token;
    var accAuthHead = "Bearer "+ accToken;

    $.ajax({
        url: "https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json",
        type: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
            'Authorization': accAuthHead.toString(),
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        },

        data: JSON.stringify(messagebody),
        datatype: "json",

        success: function (data) {
            console.log("ajax post success.");
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("There was an error with the request." + textStatus.toString()+ XMLHttpRequest.toString());
        }
    });


}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've tried your code and found two serious issues that might cause your problems:

1. You should use https://**api**.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json instead of https://**www**.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json
2. Don't JSON.stringify your data as it's supposed to be sent as just that, JSON, not as a string.

Hope it helps!

Comment: uhhh, JSON is a string... if you pass a JavaScript object to the `data` option, that will be converted into a query string. See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Juan, you're right about the fact that jQuery will turn the data into a string anyway, but it will not turn it into a stringified JSON object. It will turn it into a querystring ("?key=value&key2=value2") instead. If Blue were to provide the data as a string in querystring notation, there wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: That's exactly what I already said. You're telling the OP not to call `JSON.stringify`

Comment: Juan, I don't think you read my reply to your comment correctly. I AM telling him not to JSON.stringify because it will result in a wrong string value being sent to the jQuery.ajax method. He should either pass the original object which is conform JSON notification or create a string in querystring notification manually. JSON.stringify doesn't work here, believe me, I've tried.

Comment: I do see what you mean now, I did misread it. Their API does say that _POST_ parameters must be form encoded, not JSON encoded. I believe you should update your answer not to say `your data as it's supposed to be sent as just that, JSON`, it's supposed to be standard form encoding

Answer (score 0):

Thaks, Juan and Mark.
I changed my code in your advice. and code working now.  That is here.

```js
function sendData(msgbody) {

    //var messagebody = new FormData();

    var testMessage = {
        body: msgbody,
        group_id: 4627253
    }

    var jsonObj = JSON.stringify(testMessage);

    accToken = responseObject.access_token.token;
    var accAuthHead = 'Bearer '+ accToken;

    $.ajax({
        url: "https://api.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json",
        type: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': accAuthHead.toString(),
        },
        data: testMessage,

        success: function (data) {
            alert("ajax post success.");
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("There was an error with the request." + textStatus + XMLHttpRequest.toString());
        }
    });   
}
```

but It is a **little funny**. firstly, I tryed testing this code in "*Internet Explorer 10*". it did Not work. 
secondly, I use *Chrome(versio 39.0.2171.95 m),* it was worked!

I am little confused.
Why I get this result?