# Yammer REST API - How can I fetch data from a different origin (CORS)?

Tags: rest, api, cors, yammer

I have created a Yammer app in "My Apps" and have set my Javascript Origin to my local development URL:

http://localhost:3000

In my React app, I am trying to use the Fetch API to get some data. For example:

```
const url = 'https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/following.json';

const options = {
  method: 'GET',
  mode: 'cors',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${process.env.REACT_APP_YAMMER_ACCESS_TOKEN}`,
  }
};

fetch(url, options).then(function(response) {
  console.log(response);
  return response.json();
}).then(function(json) {
  console.log(json);
});
```

I get a CORS error:

> Access to fetch at
>   'https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/following.json' from origin
>   'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
>   mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I have my Javascript Origin set in the Yammer dashboard and I have the mode set to CORS in my fetch request. What am I missing?

Comment: Did this work for you? any solution on above issue?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with a different URL:

`const url = 'https://api.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json';`

I haven't seen this documented anywhere but I saw someone reference it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27596180/i-can-not-post-yammer-via-rest-api-using-ajax) on another StackOverflow post.